# Html style hidden for tables, td-s doesn't work well, just for div-s

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, hidden

I would like to hide and unhide some part of an html file.
The code that I use:

```
function changeVisible(colorClass, mode){
        var items = document.getElementsByClassName(colorClass);
            for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++) 
            { 
                if(mode == "0")
                {
                  items[i].setAttribute("style","");
                  items[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
                }
                else if(mode == "1")
                {
                  items[i].setAttribute("style","");
                  items[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
                  <!--items[i].style.display = 'none';-->
                }
                               }    
        }
```

The part for select the hideable parts:

```
function getURLParameters(variable, element){
               var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
               var vars = query.split("&");
               for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) 
               {
                       var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                       if(pair[0] == variable)
                       {
                            <!-- document.getElementById("cXLS").checked = pair[1]; -->
                            if(pair[1] == "true")
                            {
                                <!-- document.getElementById("cXLS").checked = true; -->
                                document.getElementById(element).setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
                                if(element == "cERR"){
                                    changeVisible("red", "1");
                                }
                            }
                            else if(pair[1] == "false"){
                                <!-- document.getElementById("cXLS").checked = false; -->
                                document.getElementById(element).removeAttribute('checked');
                                if(element == "cERR"){
                                    changeVisible("red", "0");
                                }

                            } 
                       }
               }            
        }
```

The problem is, that this works only for divs, but for table, or td not.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You shouldn't hide TDs, just TRs. Hiding TDs will mess with the table layout.

Comment: Can you set a jsfiddle.net example and show exactly what is not working? 
@Diodeus I think setting visibility to hidden won't mess the layout since td will still occupy the same space

Comment: yes, I've tried it with jsfiddle and it's work. The problem is that, this code doesn't fill the style attribute for the table, just for divs, and i don't know why

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/259By/ with a little example

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The main problem was a wrong entry point.